# Search text no matter if is in lower or upper case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I use to search content in my web using one text box `<input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />` the showing content are in different panels, so this is my `script`.

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var term = $(this).val();
    if (term != '') {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('.panel').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().indexOf(term) > -1
        }).show();
    } else {
        $('.panel').show();
    }
});
```

That works fine but only with the exactly match, if I write in the text box `Hello` shows me only the `Hello` words but I need that shows me to `hello`, `hEllO` or `HELLO`, all the string no matter the lower or upper case.

Any help is really appreciated, sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). Apply this method to both the content in the `input` and the `text()` being compared against it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert both the search string and the text you are searching in to lower case:

```
return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `toLowerCase()` function to by pass case-sensitive matching, like:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

Answer (score -1):

use `.toUpperCase()` both your input val and filter val